# Terraform - variable definition

Tags: terraform

I have inherited a project with two files:

```
a.tf
dir_name/b.tf
```

and each contains:

```
variable "region" {
  default = "us-east-1"
}
```

Is there any reason why I can't delete the variable definition from `dir_name/b.tf` as it seems to be already defined?

UPDATE

`a.tf` contains a module definition that goes like this:

```
module "dir_name" {
  source   = "./dir_name"
}
```

Comment: Are the contents of `dir` treated as a module?

Comment: No - there's no `module` definition

Comment: Ok.  When you run these, do you run terraform against the parent folder or the sub folder?

Comment: Could these be two entirely independent terraform scripts, just that one happens to be stored in a subdirectory of another?  Are there any references to `dir` from the parent, or `../` from `dir`?

Comment: Oops. It seems I missed a module definition. See my update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't remove one or the other.  Terraform works on the module level, where each module has an explicit set of input variables and output attributes;  variables can't be passed implicitly from one script to a module.

If you're passing variables from one place to another, it does currently result in a lot of repetition, eg:

```
module "dir_name" {
  source   = "./dir_name"
  region   = "${var.region}"
}
```